# Trying to install the latest version of npm but there are problems with permission

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I tried it with sudo and cleaned the cache but it still doesn't work, pls help. Thanks! It says that I have no permission to access this file as the current user but who has, i am the only user

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width\' -> \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-3e479054/node_modules/string-width',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string-width-fa87d55b' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-27T09_59_20_887Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If you are windows user, try opening terminal as administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same problem. It's not file permissions. Even chmod a+rwX -R ~/.nvm does not help and running the terminal as administrator also does not help. I tried `npm i -g jest`, and that worked just fine